# calculate orientation vector

Tags: geometry

I have a half-sphere. On the edge of the half-sphere, there is a circular cutout.

I want to place the cube on the edge of the sphere, in the circular cutout, such that the cube is perpendicular to the circular cutout. In other words, if I were to fire a ray directly from the center of the cube, it would intersect the center/base of the half-sphere and the circular cutout. I know the radius of the half-sphere and of the circular cutout. I just need to calculate the orientation vector (xyz) for the cube. How can I get it?

Below is a top-down example.

[image]

Comment: Although I think I understand what you're asking, it's not very clear how to answer your question since you haven't given any information about how you locate the circular cutout.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Thanks - just assume it is at any location on the edge of the sphere. Pick a point.